# JPA join two tables | many to one

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am facing an issue with following:

I have two tables Student and Class. I want a functionality such that whenever a student record is inserted, then student table joins to Class table on grade. example, if a student grade is A , then class name should be JUNIOR.

Note: Class table is a static table and already has been made in the sql and inserted with values.

**Student table :**

```
Name | Grade |
```

**Class Table :**

```
Grade | ClassName

A     | JUNIOR
b     | SENIOR
```

So, in the code if i want to retrieve the class to which a student is assigned , i can do something like student.getClass().getClassName()

Using JPA Hibernate how do i acheive this??

My Idea :

I create two entities , Student and Class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student")
public class Student {


private Student() {

}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String grade;
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "grade_type")
private Class class;

//Setter and getters

_______________

@Entity
@Table(name="Class")
public class Class {


private Class() {

}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "grade_type")
private String grade;
private String className;

//Setter and getters
```

And i am trying to retrieve in the code the value of class name after the student record is inserted like this :

String className = student.getClass().getClassName()

But this is not working!

Comment: Don't use Class as an entity name. It is reserved.

Comment: and `java.lang.Object` has `getClass` so you are bastardising the Java contract.

Comment: This is not a join, but just a foreign key navigation. A simple solution is to retrieve the "class" row using the FK value.